# Check if string is palindrom

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

**I cannot understand how this code works in these particular lines:**

After `DISPLAY MSG2` , How does it know to print the msg with `DISPLAY P11`?

After `DISPLAY MSG3` How does it know with these 4 lines to print the length of the array? `L1` is supposed to be "`?`" how did it get the length already?

```
 MOV DL,L1
 ADD DL,30H
 MOV AH,2
 INT 21H
```

I think I lack some knowledge about the `MACRO` and `LEA` in it. but I do know that `LEA` is `MOV blabla, OFFSET blabla2`.

Helped is highly appreciated.

```
  .MODEL SMALL
    .STACK 100h
    .DATA

        MSG1 DB 10,13,'ENTER ANY STRING :- $'
        MSG2 DB 10,13,'ENTERED STRING IS :- $'
        MSG3 DB 10,13,'LENGTH OF STRING IS :- $'
        MSG4 DB 10,13,'NO, GIVEN STRING IS NOT A PALINDROME $' 
        MSG5 DB 10,13,'THE GIVEN STRING IS A PALINDROME $'
        MSG6 DB 10,13,'REVERSE OF ENTERED STRING IS :- $'   

        P1 LABEL BYTE   ;start of label byte
        M1 DB 0FFH      ;assign maximum length of array
        L1 DB ?     ;length of string 

        P11 DB 0FFH DUP ('$')  ;init array (max 256)
        P22 DB 0FFH DUP ('$')  ;init array (max 256)

    DISPLAY MACRO MSG   ;Called like that: <Display argument>
        MOV AH,9
        LEA DX,MSG
        INT 21H
    ENDM   

    .CODE

    START:
            MOV AX,@DATA  ;Assign data to AX
            MOV DS,AX     ;Assign data to Data Segment           

            DISPLAY MSG1  ; Enter string

            LEA DX,P1 ;DX points to P1's offset
            MOV AH,0AH ; buffer filled with user input   
            INT 21H

            DISPLAY MSG2  ;The entered string is:

            DISPLAY P11   ;This will display the string

            DISPLAY MSG3  ;Display length

            ;Ap

ply string's length to DL,
        ; covert from ASCII to DEC, and output the length value.
        MOV DL,L1
        ADD DL,30H
        MOV AH,2
        INT 21H

        DISPLAY MSG6

        ;initialize P11 to SI register and P22 to DI register       
        LEA SI,P11
        LEA DI,P22

        ;Jump SI to the end of string
        MOV DL,L1
        DEC DL
        MOV DH,0
        ADD SI,DX                  

        ;Move length of actual string to CL, and apply CH = 0
        MOV CL,L1
        MOV CH,0    
        ;CX = string's length.

REVERSE:    
        ;Put P11's REVERESED string into P22 string
        MOV AL,[SI]
        MOV [DI],AL
        INC DI
        DEC SI
        LOOP REVERSE

        DISPLAY P22  ; Display the reversed string

        ;Re-assign P11,P22 to SI,DI registers              
        LEA SI,P11
        LEA DI,P22   

        ;Move length of actual string to CL, and apply CH = 0
        MOV CL,L1
        MOV CH,0    
        ;CX = string's length.

CHECK:
        MOV AL,[SI]
        CMP [DI],AL
        JNE NOTPALIN
        INC DI
        INC SI
        LOOP CHECK


        DISPLAY MSG5
        JMP EXIT
NOTPALIN:
        DISPLAY MSG4

EXIT:   MOV AH,4CH
        INT 21H
CODE ENDS
END START
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the [function 0Ah in int 21h](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a) you give it a buffer in a certain format. The first byte (`M1` here) says how many bytes the buffer has, the second will have the number of bytes read (`L1` here) and after that the bytes that will have the actual characters read (`P11` here).

So after calling the read function `L1` is initialized with the number of characters read.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS P1 and M1 point to the same place so only one would be needed.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how can I upgrade the code to do the following: If the string is palindrom, I want to check if we don't have more than twice the same chars. for example 'aba' is fine, but 'aabaa' is not, because 'a' is repeated twice.(although it is a palindrom)

Comment: maybe make an array with 26 spaces, and increase the space's index depending on the char i'm "standing on" in the loop, and then check the array, if it has a space filled with number '4' then not palindrom?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS That would work. 0 or 2 is ok, more than that not.